# Gnuplot fit error : Singular matrix in Givens()

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting

I want to fit a function with a dataset using gnuplot.

I use a data set example, in the file "data":

```
1 2
5 4
6 5
7 8
```

If I do in gnuplot

```
>f(x) = a*x+b
>fit f(x) "data" via a,b
```

It works just good, (and with this example I get a≃0.855 and b≃0.687)

Now what I really want to do is to fit the function `floor(a*x+b)`. So I tried exactly the same way

```
>f(x) = floor(a*x+b)
>fit f(x) "data" via a,b
```

And I get the output

```
 Iteration 0
 WSSR        : 8                 delta(WSSR)/WSSR   : 0
 delta(WSSR) : 0                 limit for stopping : 1e-005
 lambda   : 0

initial set of free parameter values

a               = 1
b               = 1
         Singular matrix in Givens()
         error during fit
```

Googling it didn't help me, I also tried to find if there was some contraindication using fit with floor but again I didn't find anything.

Has someone an idea?

Note : I use Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0, built for Windows 32bit

Answer (score 4):

There is a fundamental problem fitting with floor, which is that your least squares error function is piecewise constant, so when you look for the gradient of the error with respect to your fit parameters you always get zero.

In this example the minimum sum of squares error is exactly 3 for a range of a,b in the neighborhood of .85,1.5

Mathermatica, (which is far more poweful), gives a result 1,1 along with a warning that due to the zero gradient it can not be sure if this is really a minimum.